# Why method based on streams takes so long to finish?

Tags: java, java-stream, cpu, cpu-usage

I have been doing some practice tests at HackerRank and at some point decided to solve it using only streams (as a personal challenge). I did it. Program works in general. However, when it comes to **big amounts of data** it needs to go over, program takes a **long** time to do it. Because of that, ultimately I didn't solve the test because of "Terminated due to timeout :(". And I totally agree. When I run this program on my own PC, not only did it took a long to finish, but my CPU temperature skyrocketed during the work...

Here is the code I created:

```
List<Integer> duplicatesCount = arr.stream()
        .map(x -> Collections.frequency(arr, x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
OptionalInt maxDuplicate = duplicatesCount.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max();
Set<Integer> duplicates = arr.stream()
        .filter(x -> Collections.frequency(arr, x) == maxDuplicate.getAsInt())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
OptionalInt result = duplicates.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min();
return result.getAsInt();
```

Can someone explain this to me? Does streams in general put so much pressure on the CPU? Or is it just this program?

PS. The data I mentioned above (the one that this program couldn't handle) had 73966 digits from 1 to 5. If that is important or interests someone...

Comment: `duplicatesCount` is counted by iterating the whole array for every element in the array, i.e. it is quadratic. `arr.stream().collect(groupingBy(a -> a, counting()))` would be a far more efficient way to count the frequency of each element.

Comment: Relevant to understand the [time complexity of `Collections.frequency`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734589/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-javas-in-built-function-collections-frequencylis)

Comment: @Naman  I don't get the answer to that question... Time complexity of this collection is "o(n)"? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`duplicatesCount` is counted by iterating the whole array for every element in the array, i.e. it is quadratic.

So, to handle an array of 73,966 elements, you are doing 5,470,969,156 comparisons. That's quite a lot.

```
Map<Integer, Long> freqs = arr.stream().collect(groupingBy(a -> a, counting()))
```

would be a far more efficient way to count the frequency of each element. This is roughly the same as:

```
Map<Integer, Long> freqs = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer i : arr) {
  freqs.merge(i, 1L, Long::sum);
}
```

i.e. it just increments a map value for each element in the array.

Then, it looks like you are looking for the smallest number with the maximum frequency:

```
int minNum = 0;
long maxFreq = 0;
for (Entry<Integer, Long> e : freqs.entrySet()) {
  if (e.getValue() > maxFreq) {
    minNum = e.getKey();
    maxFreq = e.getValue();
  } else if (e.getValue() == maxFreq) {
    minNum = Math.min(minNum, e.getKey());
  }
}
return minNum;
```

You can do this with lambdas too:

```
return Collections.max(freqs.entrySet(),
    Comparator.<Entry<Integer, Long>>comparingLong(Entry::getKey).thenComparing(Comparator.<Entry<Integer, Key>>comparingInt(Entry::getValue).reversed())).getKey();
```

but I think the imperative way is clearer.

This all runs in linear time.

Comment: Thanks. Why is groupingBy faster than freaquency? Does groupingBy not go through all the elements?

Comment: @StanleyLapinski it doesn't count all the elements for each element in the array. It just increments a map value by one each time a number is encountered.

Comment: Oh... Yeah, that seems like a much better strategy to do this xd

Comment: The last line of code doesn't seem correct (certainly for `Comparator.<Entry<Integer, Key>` part). The actual code corresponding to *the smallest number with the maximum frequency*, might look like `return freqs.entrySet().stream()
                .min(Comparator.<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed()
                        .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .orElseThrow(IllegalAccessException::new);`